# Cannot edit "Network endpoint group" and Network endpoints in the group after creating it in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I just create a Network endpoint group based on the instructions in https://www.albinsblog.com/2020/06/how-to-enable-google-cdn-for-custom-origin-websites.html#.YPTQgab7SM8. However, after that, when I try to check the group, I can see its details, but there are no option to edit it, such as changing the default port. The only option is to "Delete" it.

The same thing happens in the network endpoints in this group. I can remove one network endpoints, but cannot edit its IP address or port.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

After you create the internet NEG, the type cannot be changed between INTERNET_FQDN_PORT and INTERNET_IP_PORT. You need to create a new internet NEG and change your backend service to use the new internet NEG. Each endpoint is specified either by an IP address or an IP:port combination. you can only attach endpoints that belong to a VM's primary internal IP address in NEG's VPC network. Primary internal IP addresses from any NIC of a multi-NIC VM can be added to a NEG if the NEG uses the same VPC network as the NIC.

Every endpoint in the NEG must be a unique IP address and port combination. A unique endpoint IP address and port combination can be referenced by more than one NEG.

Each endpoint VM must have a network interface (NIC) in the same VPC network as the NEG. Endpoint IP addresses must be associated with the same subnet specified in the NEG.

I suggest you refer to [Troubleshooting NEG issues](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/troubleshooting-ext-https-lbs#custom-origins-internet-neg), [Setting up Cloud CDN with an external backend](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/setting-up-cdn-with-ex-backend-internet-neg).